# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no alert open

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, alerts

Using Selenium Webdriver,I tried to open fb page after logging in. Once I logged in ,there is a pop up box appearing as follows
"Show notifications
    Allow and Block"
I want to select "***Allow***" button.

I got an error message as

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no alert open

Please help.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\ABCD\\Desktop\\chromedRiver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");      
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys("xxx");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pass']")).sendKeys("xxx");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='u_0_m']")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
Alert alert=driver.switchTo().alert();
String msg= alert.getText();
System.out.println(msg);
Thread.sleep(2000);
alert.accept();
```

Comment: It is not a native alert must be an iframe.
You need to switch to the frame and click the option you want

Comment: It is actually a browser notification, it is not part of the DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an alert as stated by Zach, it is a browser notification, and in your case you can press the allow button just by sending the Space Key using the `Robot` class in Java:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
```

So the code would be:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\ABCD\\Desktop\\chromedRiver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");      
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys("xxx");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pass']")).sendKeys("xxx");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='u_0_m']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

I am not sure if there is a way to retrieve the notification message though as you were trying to do.